# Issue with SLRE regex to find data between two tags

Tags: c++, c, regex, regex-negation

I have a string

`static const char *str = ",<ABC$>EEEEEEEE$>,EEE<$WQWERRERR<$ABC>,2233My Name Is $Tom,<ABC$>$>,TTTTTTTEEE<$WQWERRERR<$ABC>,2233My Name Is Jake,<ABC$>$>";`

I want to get all text in between `<ABC$>,` header  and `,<ABC$>` footer.

Now if I am using expression

```
static const char *regex = "<\\$ABC>,([^>]*),<ABC\\$>";
```

Notice that I am using `[^>]` to make it **non-greedy**.

and printing it using

```
 struct slre_cap caps[2];
    int i, j = 0, str_len = strlen(str);

    while (j < str_len &&
       (i = slre_match(regex, str + j, str_len - j, caps, 2)) > 0) {
      printf("Found Data: [%.*s]\n", caps[0].len, caps[0].ptr);
      j += i;
    }
```

My output looks like

```
 Found Data: [2233My Name Is $Tom]
 Found Data: [2233My Name Is Jake]
```

Everything is fine until this point, but now to add a curve ball I introduced a `>` (which a binary serialization protocol e.g. protobuf-embedded-c that I plan to use later *may* introduce) character in between the header and the footer e.g. `<$ABC>,2233My Name Is> $Tom,<ABC$>`. Now suddenly, the result is different. Thus I was wondering if there is a way to instead **negate** the word `ABC` rather than a single character `>` for non-greedy approach. Other regex libraries do this using negative lookahead/lookbehind to my knowledge, which is not available in SLRE. Is it possible to simulate this behavior in SLRE? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe regular expressions are not the right tool here. You can find your subexpressions simply by searching for your fixed delimiting strings:

```
const char *p = str;

for (;;) {
    const char *q, *r;
    int len;

    r = strstr(p, "<$ABC>");
    if (r == NULL) break;
    r += 6;

    q = strstr(r + 6, "<ABC$>");
    if (q == NULL) break;

    len = q - r;
    printf("'%.*s'\n", len, r);
    p = q + 6;
}
```

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, the captured string between delimiters must of course start after the beginning delimiter, but `strstr` finds its beginning. Hence, the length of the delimiting string, here 6, must be added to `r`.

In the same way, if the captured string should include the delimiters, `r` stays as it is after the `strstr` search and the length of the end delimiter must be added to `q`:

```
    r = strstr(p, "<$ABC>");
    if (r == NULL) break;

    q = strstr(r + 6, "<ABC$>");
    if (q == NULL) break;
    q += 6;

    len = q - r;
    printf("'%.*s'\n", len, r);
    p = q;
```

Comment: That works as expected. I had to though modify the following `len = q - r-6;` and `printf("'%.*s'\n", len, r+6);`

Comment: @M Oehm, Thank you. I think I also learned that regex although very helpful sometimes has simpler alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `([^>]*)` with `(.*?)`. dot(`.`) means any character. Whereas in your code `[^>]` means any character other than a `>`.

Comment: Actually I already gave that a shot before posting this question but it doesn't seem to work with SLRE. Thanks for suggestion though.